# Laravel route group issue (blank page)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

config: laravel 5.5

web.php

```
Route::group([
    // 'middleware' => ['auth', 'is_admin'],
    'namespace'  => 'Admin',
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    ], 
    function () {
        Route::get('/', function(){
                return 'admin';
            });

        Route::get('/pages', 'AdminController@pages')->name('admin_pages');
});
```

php artisan route:list
http://prntscr.com/moltmg

but get http://prntscr.com/moluky empty page

I don’t know what the problem is, I’m registering the path, I’ll use group, but I’m getting a blank page, no error, nothing. Other path work fine, also if I register a path in a group, for example:
 **admin / dashboard** 
everything is fine, only this one does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload -o
```

if still not working.
provide 777 permission to storage and bootstrap/cache folders.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the `route::get` in your group.

this is an example that can help you :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
//All the routes that you have :
Route::get('/pages', 'AdminController@pages')->name('admin_pages');
});
```

Hope this helps :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the disturb, I am an idiot and created the "admin" folder in the "public" folder.